# md-input placeholder doesn't fade when loading formgroup value via promise from service

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In angular2 I am trying the new way of loading data to my input. I am using formgroup so that I can keep my HTML clean and have more validation logic in component ts file. My code to render form element is below:-

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UsersService,
        private router: Router, private accountRoutes: AccountRoutes) {
        this.myForm =

            this.myForm = this._fb.group({
                user: this._fb.group({
                    "EmailAddress": [null, Validators.compose([
                        Validators.required
                    ])]
                })
            });

    }
ngOnInit() {

        this.userService.GetUser().subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.user = {
                    EmailAddress: "aaa@aaa.com",//response.EmailAddress,
                    FirstName: response.FirstName,
                    MiddleName: response.MiddleName,
                    Surname: response.Surname,
                    Password: "",
                    ConfirmPassword: ""
                };
                this.myForm.controls["user"].setValue(this.user, { onlySelf: true });
            });
```

});
        }

And Html code is below:

```
<md-card-content fxLayout="column" formGroupName="user">
   <md-input-container>
     <input md-input placeholder="Email" formControlName="EmailAddress"
                               type="email" name="EmailAddress" />
   </md-input-container>
</md-card-content>
```

Please look at the following image for more details on issue. As you can see in the image that when I loaded my data from back-end the place holder still staying in the background
[image]
But whenever I am loading my data for form element from backend API place holder is not moving up.

Comment: I found the culprit it is the md-empty class that is getting added to md-input but never getting removed. "<label class="md-input-placeholder md-empty md-float" for="md-input-0">Email <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--></label>". I don't know why this is not getting removed from md-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem can be found here. This issue has been fixed in master branch which will be releasing soon.

[https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3117#event-964077880][1]